# Transaction express cURL with PHP integration is not working?

Tags: php, curl

This code is used to send details to a payment gateway. When I am using the code for my normal form it works fine but when use it with cURL in PHP it not working and gives the result "Object is moved".

What is the solution to my problem? How can I use cURL in the Transaction express gateway for payment transfer?

Here is the code that causes the issue:

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
    $postData = '';
    //create name value pairs seperated by &
    foreach($params as $k => $v) 
    { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($postData, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
    $output=curl_exec($ch) or die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
$params = array(
   "HostedKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "Gateway_ID" => "xxxxxxxx",
   "IndustryCode" => "2",
   "Amount" => "",
   "RecurringType" => "N",
   "RecurringAmount" => "",
   "RURL" => "http://www.example.com",
   "CURL" => "http://www.example.com",
   "AVSRequired" => "N",
   "CVV2Required" => "Y",
   "EmailRequired" => "Y",
   "PostRspMsg" => "N",
   "FullName" => "my name",
   "CustRefID" => "11111111"
);
echo httpPost("https://hosted.transactionexpress.com/Transaction/Transaction/Index/",$params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of ssl for security reason

You have to do something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

OR

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case for PayPal payments:

```
 $pp_hostname = "www.paypal.com";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);      
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));

 $res = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use curl? It is an obsolete way of consuming APIs.

Use SOAP WSDL for a more robust and OOP approach checkout my example

https://github.com/rojobo/TransactionExpressPHP

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for call Transaction Express payment gatway. 
Let's take example of sendTran mathod .
The code will be like following .

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://ws.cert.transactionexpress.com/portal/merchantframework/MerchantWebServices-v1?wsdl",array('exceptions'=>FALSE));

$params = array("tranCode" => 1,
                 "reqAmt" => 0200
                 );

$SendTran = $client->__soapCall("SendTran", array("parameters" => $params));
```